# UICollectionView List Layout not correctly highlighting cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a problem for which I can't provide much code, but need some pointers.

In iOS 14, Apple introduced `sidebar` as `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration.Appearance` option.

Following tutorials like [these](https://blog.timroesner.com/diffable-data-source-cell-registration-sidebar), I noticed the highlighting style looked like this:

[image]

This matches Apple's style across the OS.

I followed this tutorial and implemented things the same way, but got this result:

[image]

In both cases (the tutorial and my implementation), only default UICollectionViewListCell styles are used, I'm not creating a subclass.

My cell setup looks like this:

```swift
let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, FolderRowV2> { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
    
    var contentConfiguration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    contentConfiguration.image = itemIdentifier.image()
    contentConfiguration.text = itemIdentifier.title()
    if itemIdentifier.isHeaderItem() {
        cell.accessories = [.outlineDisclosure()]
    }
    cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
}
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app while a hardware keyboard is attached, including when run in the iOS Simulator, the highlight appears gray when focus is not on that cell but the cell is selected. You can use the tab and arrow keys to move focus to the cell in the sidebar which will fill it with the accent color. That way it's clear to the user what view is currently in focus and also which cell in the sidebar is selected. For example it would be confusing if the cell were accented in the primary column and another collection view cell in the secondary column were accented with a focus ring because you wouldn't be able to tell where focus is.

When you run the app on a physical device without a keyboard attached, the selected cell will always be highlighted the accent color since there's nothing ever in focus.